# How to debug a cap deploy error and find log files for Net::SSH::ChannelOpenFailed network error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, capistrano, net-ssh

I run into *Net::SSH::ChannelOpenFailed* error when deploying (the error occurs at capistrano's assets:precompile task - see assets.rb below) and only on one server of two. Both servers have similar installation (Gentoo kernel 3.6, Ruby 1.9.3, rails gem 3.2.12, net-ssh gem 2.6.5), but only one gives me this error.

```
> cap -vv deploy:update_code

  servers: ["31.131.19.xxx", "network.local"]
  [network.local] executing command
  [31.131.19.xxx] executing command
  command finished in 269ms
* executing "ls -x /home/deployer/apps/network/releases"
  servers: ["31.131.19.xxx"]
  /usr/local/lib64/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.6.5/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:524:in
  `do_open_failed': open failed (1) (Net::SSH::ChannelOpenFailed)
```

`cap deploy:check` runs well. Fresh deploy (with all previous releases removed from the production server) goes without problems. Running migrations immediately after throws the error (at assets:precompile).

I can't find any logs or anything that would help me to understand what is going on, particularly where this `ls -x /home/deployer/apps/network/releases` came from, what is it doing in assets:precompile task and why do I get the error above.

I had an idea of v8 and therubyracer gems being out of sync, but running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on the server proved these gems are updated.

Where do I start debugging?

**assets.rb (excerpt)**

```
 task :precompile, :roles => assets_role, :except => { :no_release => true } do
   logger.info "... Runs okay until this point ..."
   run <<-CMD.compact
     cd -- #{latest_release.shellescape} &&
     #{rake} RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env.to_s.shellescape} #{asset_env} assets:precompile &&
     cp -- #{shared_path.shellescape}/assets/manifest.yml #{current_release.shellescape}/assets_manifest.yml
   CMD
   logger.info "... Never gets here ..."
 end
```

**deploy.rb**

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
load 'lib/deploy/seed'

set :application, "network"
set :rails_env, "production"

server "31.131.19.xxx", :web, :app, :db, primary: true
server "network.local", :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :bundle_roles, [:app]
set :normalize_asset_timestamps, false

set :user, "deployer"
set :group, "deployer"

set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :copy_exclude, ".git/*"

set :use_sudo, false
set :scm, "git"

set :repository, "git@bitbucket.org:danchenkov/#{application}.git"

set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

set :unicorn_conf, "#{deploy_to}/current/config/unicorn.rb"
set :unicorn_pid, "#{deploy_to}/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"

after 'deploy:update_code', :roles => :app do
  run "rm -f #{current_release}/config/database.yml"
  run "ln -s #{deploy_to}/shared/config/database.yml #{current_release}/config/database.yml"
end

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup"

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/vhosts/#{application}.upstream.conf"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/log"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/pids"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/sockets"
    put File.read("config/database.yml"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'

gem 'pg'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'libv8-3.11.8.13-x86_64-linux', :platform => :ruby
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby, :require => 'v8'
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby'

# Deploy with Capistrano
gem 'capistrano'

# Style
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'simple_form'

# Templates
gem 'redcarpet'

# Attachments
gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'

# Pagination
gem 'kaminari'

# Auth & Roles
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'

gem 'unicode'
gem 'unicorn', :platform => :ruby
```

Comment: what would the -v verbose flag give for additional info?

Comment: adding -v or -vv to `cap deploy` does not make any difference. Same output (which is not clear enough for me).

Comment: I think, the command that is making problems is an ssh -c "ls -x /home/deployer/apps/network/releases" ... maybe you could try it from the command line

Comment: I believe -c stands for cipher_type (irrelevant), but running `ssh 31.131.19.xxx "ls -x /home/deployer/apps/network/releases"` just lists my releases, as expected.

Comment: Could be an issue of `:max_hosts` option? Tried setting it to a larger value?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue here, but you better update your local ruby to the same versions as on server, and run:

```
gem update --system (on both: server and local machines)
```

For your issue, try:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh deployer@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

This will allow you to ssh into the server without entering a password, and it will store server ssh, on your local machine. If you have done this before, you may try to delete this ssh from publickeys, and rerun this command.